How to integrate filament to existing API app
I have a production ready API with laravel 11 and I want to integrate filament for some pretty views, but I want to integrate filament (create,update,list) with my existing API and not to default filament CRUD operation directly with models. For example I want to send create submit form to my API
p.s
Route::post('/teachers', [TeacherController::class, 'store']);
and edit to
Route::put('/teachers/{id}', [TeacherController::class, 'update']);
How can I integrate it ?
Thanks you anyway!
I use filament for the first time and I have no idea how to customize filament with existing API endpoints
please do not post any solution from chatGPT

As of Filament v3, it is not possible to directly display non-Eloquent queries into Filament tables (this feature is coming to Filament v4).
As a workaround to display data, you can use a package such as Sushi to  query your API data as Eloquent models:
class Role extends Model
{
    use \Sushi\Sushi;

    public function getRows()
    {
        return Http::get('/teachers')->json('users');
    }
}

As for record editing, I think your best bet is to use a custom creation and edit actions that use forms and post data to your APIs (both on the list page as a header action for the create action and as a row action for the edit action):
public function table(Table $table): Table
{
    return $table
        ->actions([
            Action::make('edit')
              ->form([
                 TextInput::make('name')
              ])
              ->action(fn($data) => Http::post('/teachers', $data))
        ]);
}


I would like to mention that filament has two types of resources

default resource where you use the command : php artisan make:filament-resource Customer as an example
simple resource where you use : php artisan make:filament-resource Customer --simple

you can find more about that in the document filament documentation get started
assuming that you are working on the first type of resource, you would likely have a resource structure like this

so to customize the creation process go to App/Filament/Resource/PostResource/CreatePost

add the method
        protected function handleRecordCreation(array $data): Model
        {
                    // Your logic here .......
                    Http::post(url('/api/teachers'), $data);
                  //reutn $model

        }

then add method to handle redirect
protected function getRedirectUrl(): string
{
    return $this->getResource()::getUrl('index');
}

this is the way mentioned in the documentation check here

to handle the edit action go to App/Filament/Resource/PostResource/EditPost as example
protected function handleRecordUpdate(Model $record, array $data): Model
{
    //your logic here
    Http::put(url('/api/teachers/' . $this->record->id), $data);
    return $record;
}


handle the edit action redirect using the method 
protected function getRedirectUrl(): string
{
    return $this->getResource()::getUrl('index');
}

and again you can find all of these in the documentation cech here

you can change the create/update process, put your logic to call the existing API instead of actually creating the record using Eloquent
https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/panels/resources/creating-records#customizing-the-creation-process
https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/panels/resources/editing-records#customizing-the-saving-process
